# Javascript filter over HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, loops, filter, console, htmlcollection

I want to get particular query params from all the js files which have been loaded by the browser. My query params reside in the js file named `script.js`(ex:  https://abcd.com/script.js?code=123). In the browser console, I tried like this:

```
const scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT")
scripts.filter((script) => { return script.src.includes("script.js?code=")})
```

But this returns the error `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).filter is not a function`. Please suggest the code changes or is there any better way to get the same?

Comment: HTMLCollection is not array, make it an array like this: `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"));`. There's also [document.scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scripts) collection available, using it saves a couple of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods like getElementsByTagName do not return an array rather a list of node.
Just wrap your queryselector with brackets and the spread operator to create an array from the nodelist.

```
const scripts = [...document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT")]
scripts.filter((script) => { return script.src.includes("script.js?code=")})
```